# EU: Medical insurance mandatory at border control?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, insurance, permits

I am a non-EU citizen travelling to Sweden on a work/residence permit. I have health insurance cover through my employer, but I do not have any documentation to support that except for a 'Yes' under 'Insured?' section of my appointment letter.

1. Are insurance documents checked at border control?
2. If yes, then is the 'Yes' in the appointment letter sufficient?

Comment: Can you get something from them in advance? Might be wise anyway, otherwise what would happen if you (say) had an accident in the airport and needed treatment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have arrived in Sweden and can now answer my own question.

Even though I had insurance from my employer, I did not have any supporting documents. So I bought a 60 day travel-cum-medical insurance for me and my wife. We crossed the border control without any problems. The border guard did not ask anything.

To sum up, even though its mandatory to have an insurance when travelling to EU, in practice border guards rarely ask for proof. Anyway, having insurance is always a good idea. If not long term, choose a limited period insurance which will cover you till you get settled in the new place.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to share your experience! To complement your answer, medical insurance is mentioned in the Schengen visa code but not in the borders code so the idea seems to be that it is checked when applying for a visa and not at the border. Of course, IANAL applies.

Answer (score 1):

All EU residents, including non-EU nationals working in EU are obliged to be insured in public health insurance systems. Systems vary between each EU country, but what does not vary is that it's mandatory.

While traveling within EU, the document required as proof of insurance is [**European Health Insurance Card**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Health_Insurance_Card). These cards are provided **for free**, all you need to do is apply to get one.

It wasn't obvious from the question, but you've clarified that you were traveling from outside of EU to country where you're going to be resident. I wouldn't expect requirement for travel insurance, which is required for short stays. On the other hand becoming legal resident you fall under public health insurance scheme.

Comment: European Health Insurance Card is [not delivered to non European citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Health_Insurance_Card#Participating_countries).

Comment: @mouviciel: eh? *"**anyone** who is insured by or covered by a statutory social security scheme of the EEA countries and Switzerland"*. Why would you say that it doesn't apply for non-citizen residents? The part of the article you linked to only talks of Channel Islands and Isle of Man.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see at first that he was a resident.

Comment: @vartec I am travelling from India and will be crossing  the Schengen border in Helsinki.

Comment: The way I read the question, it's not about traveling within Schengen so the answer isn't really relevant.

Comment: @Annoyed: it wasn't quite clear from the question, edited now

Comment: @vartec Yes, I see how you could interpret it differently, that's why I said “the way I read the question” (the downvote doesn't come from me, btw ;-)